Why doesn't the MDX Order function with ASC sort all crossjoined hierarchies (as the SSAS doc suggests)?
Version
I am using Microsoft Analysis Services 16.0.43.229.
Question
I do not understand some behaviour of the Order function when using a Crossjoin with ASC ordering as it does not seem to match the documentation.  It seems that it is only sorting the last hierarchy, but the documentation says this should only be the case if DESC is used:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/order-mdx?view=sql-server-ver16

If ASC or DESC is specified, the Order function first arranges the
members according to their position in the hierarchy, and then orders
each level.
If the Order function is used with a set where two or more hierarchies
are crossjoined, and the DESC flag is used, only the members of the
last hierarchy in the set are ordered. This is a change from Analysis
Services 2000 where all hierarchies in the set were ordered.

Order with 1 hierarchy ASC
The following MDX shows the order for the first hierarchy:
SELECT {[Measures].[Tax Amount]} ON 0,
Order([Sales Territory].[Sales Territory].[Group].Members,
[Measures].[Tax Amount], ASC) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]




Territory
Tax Amount




NA
(null)


Pacific
$852,426.90


Europe
$1,584,046.16


North America
$6,348,268.77



Order with 2 hierarchies crossjoined ASC
If I add a second hierarchy in a Crossjoin, I would expect this first hierarchy to remain in that order (as I am using ASC and not DESC), but instead it sorts the first hierarchy in member order:
SELECT {[Measures].[Tax Amount]} ON 0,
Order([Sales Territory].[Sales Territory].[Group].Members
* [Product].[Product Categories].[Category].Members,
[Measures].[Tax Amount], ASC) ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]




Territory
Category
Tax Amount




Europe
Accessories
$26,238.18


Europe
Clothing
$32,110.44


Europe
Components
$153,348.64


Europe
Bikes
$1,372,348.90


NA
Accessories
(null)


NA
Bikes
(null)


NA
Clothing
(null)


NA
Components
(null)


North America
Accessories
$62,515.40


North America
Clothing
$128,244.56


North America
Components
$774,285.38


North America
Bikes
$5,383,223.44


Pacific
Clothing
$9,054.06


Pacific
Accessories
$13,011.05


Pacific
Components
$16,292.11


Pacific
Bikes
$814,069.68



Please could someone clarify the documentation.  Why is it only sorting by the second hierarchy?  I would expect the result to be:



Territory
Category
Tax Amount




NA
Accessories
(null)


NA
Bikes
(null)


NA
Clothing
(null)


NA
Components
(null)


Pacific
Clothing
$9,054.06


Pacific
Accessories
$13,011.05


Pacific
Components
$16,292.11


Pacific
Bikes
$814,069.68


Europe
Accessories
$26,238.18


Europe
Clothing
$32,110.44


Europe
Components
$153,348.64


Europe
Bikes
$1,372,348.90


North America
Accessories
$62,515.40


North America
Clothing
$128,244.56


North America
Components
$774,285.38


North America
Bikes
$5,383,223.44




When sorting, ASC will sort within hierarchies. In this case it will sort Categories within each Territory.
To sort categories across all territories you should use BASC, where B stands for "hierarchy breaking".
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/order-mdx?view=sql-server-ver16

I know that ASC will not break the hierarchy, but my question is that the documentation suggests each hierachy in the crossjoin will be sorted, so I would have expected the second table to show all NA members first.
